# How to compy specific png files from one folder to other folder

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have folder A with .png files in computer i want to copy some specific png files from folder A to new folder

```
folder A = 2323.png,4454.png,55656.png

list of png that need to copy in other folder from folder A
[2323,55656]
```

in pandas how to do this task ?

Comment: you just want to copy files to another folder?  Why would you use pandas for that?

Comment: @anon01 in folder i have 1000 files , i want to copy some specific files to other folder